# scrape values from nested json dicts

Tags: json, regex, python-3.x, dictionary

I have data like the example below.  It has dict, which has keys that are lists.  Those lists also contain dicts.  I want to create a list like the desired output below, where I've scraped the "Id" values from the data.  I've been working on writing for loops to pull the values, then filter by keys and  and values.  I'm thinking maybe there's an easier way like just using regex pattern matching to grab everything that has pattern "u'Id':u'integer'". Does anyone see an easier way, or can suggest code to scrape the "Id" values from the nested dict below?

data:

```
{u'distinct': [{u'__class__': u'tuple',
   u'__value__': [{u'Id': u'9624',
     u'classification': u'i',

     u'storeid': u'86'},

    {u'Id': u'41822',
     u'classification': u's/i',

     u'storeid': u'86'}]}],
 u'match': [{u'__class__': u'tuple',
   u'__value__': [{u'Id': u'38916',
     u'classification': u'c',

     u'storeid': u'125'},
    {u'Id': u'49462',
     u'classification': u'n/a',

     u'storeid': u'124'}]},
      {u'Id': u'46525',
     u'classification': u'h',
          u'storeid': u'158'}]}]}
```

desired output:

```
[9624,41822,49462,46525]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two extra `]` and `}` in the dictionary, you have posted, if that'd be true, then you can just loop through and see where your desired Ids are:

```
d = {u'distinct': [{u'__class__': u'tuple', u'__value__': [{u'Id': u'9624', u'classification': u'i', u'storeid': u'86'}, {u'Id': u'41822', u'classification': u's/i', u'storeid': u'86'}]}], u'match': [{u'__class__': u'tuple',
                                                                                                                                                                                                         u'__value__': [{u'Id': u'38916', u'classification': u'c', u'storeid': u'125'}, {u'Id': u'49462', u'classification': u'n/a', u'storeid': u'124'}]}, {u'Id': u'46525', u'classification': u'h', u'storeid': u'158'}]}
output = []
for item in d.items():
    for ID in item[1][0]['__value__']:
        output.append(int(ID['Id']))

print(output)
```

#### Output

```
[9624, 41822, 38916, 49462]
```

Comment: thank you for getting back to me so quicly with this.  I tried your suggestion, it only returns the first 4 Id values from my data.  I think the "]}" are correct.